# Getting radeon driver working and set higher resolution on GNU/Linux X11 X.org AMD Radeon

Tags: x11, xorg, xrandr, amd-graphics, radeon

When trying to set a higher resolution using xrandr, I get

```
Failed to get size of gamma for output default
```

Also `lsmod | grep radeon` returns no output meaning that the Radeon driver is not in use. According to [this page](https://www.x.org/wiki/RadeonFeature/), my graphics card is fully supported.

What I have tried so far:

- After reading [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver), I tried to disable/removing my `/etc/x11/xorg.conf` but it didn't help.
- Load video driver at boot time with /etc/rc.conf: `kld_list="radeonkms"` [(from freebsd.org)](https://wiki.freebsd.org/Graphics)

I have the following Kernel: **Linux 3.13.0-xx-lowlatency** on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Trusty Thar

My graphics card is in the **Evergreen** family.

What can I do to get the radeon driver working?

Comment: Could you update your post to include what Distro you are using? This can help isolate what packages and dependencies are needed to get your graphics driver working. The [Official Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/AtiHowTo) has a straight forward guide on getting your AMD graphics working but steps will be different even for other Debian derivative Distros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get the radeon driver working. It was blacklisted, so I had to disable (rename or remove) the file `/etc/modprobe.d/disable-radeon.conf`. Additionally, I added `radeon` to `/etc/modules` and put `options radeon modeset=1` in `/etc/modprobe.d/`.

Now reboot and check `lsmod | grep radeon`.

[Radeon KMS and DRI2](http://bgoglin.livejournal.com/19346.html)